# In Keras, how to get the mean of the difference between predicted and actual values

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I would like to get the **mean difference between the model predictions and the real values**, here is a graph showing the two corresponding values (in red: predictions, in blue: real values):

[image]

I have tried to use the metrics called **mean_absolute_error**, like so:

`model.compile(optimizer=adam, loss=loss_function, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"])`

But then when I evaluate:

`model.evaluate(x_test,y_test, batch_size=60)`

I get this result:

> 5/5 [==============================] - 1s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0011 -
> mean_absolute_error: **0.0201**

You can see that **0.0201** does not correspond to the mean of the difference between predictions and real values (just look at the values after Days 200, the spread between the two lines is in the order of 10 000s..).

So, any idea on how I could get the mean between predictions and real values ?

Thank you

p.s:

You can find the code on Google Colab [here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1puRQre0FIR2NGUz_eMzQ-SmgAJtJY4pm?usp=sharing). In case the code does not load the weights, you can take them [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aymeric75/IA/master/weights_bitcoin.h5).

Comment: this error (0.0201) is computed on the scaled data. you have to inverse scale both predictions and actual values... keras model.evaluate doesn't do this

Comment: Did you tried to calculate price as suggested above? Generally for assessing accuracy on a single series, I prefer the MAE because it is easiest to understand and compute. However, it cannot be compared across series because it is scale dependent.